# Viewing ArcGIS webservice from MS Windows

Tags: arcgis-server

We setup web GIS service using the combination of ArcGIS Server and Oracle. We put the spatial data in Oracle and use ArcGIS Server to publish the service.

Currently we have a problem in viewing the web GIS from computer using MS Windows, but can view it using Ubuntu Linux and Mac OS X. If we view the service using MS Windows, sometimes all of the function works but most of times they fail.

If you have had this kind of problem, what was the solution?

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are getting when 'viewing the WebGIS'? Can you explain what you mean by 'viewing the WebGIS'?

Comment: Posting the actual error message would be helpful...when you say the functions fail, do they just dont do anything or throw an error dialog?

Comment: Please provide software specification( ex. ArcGIS Server v. 10.0/10.1 ,ArcSDE version 9.3/10 etc.) also is it single box installation or distributed installation ?

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

@DevdattaTengshe: What I mean by viewing is open the application via browser. The application includes common function and shows 3 regions (Sumatera, Java and Borneo), but some users sometimes can only view 1 region only.

To ujjwalesri: Unfortunately I don't have the access to the server right now. I hope tomorrow I can save the error log.

To Sunil: The configuration of the system is: ArcGIS Server 10.1 in RHEL 6.3 and Oracle 11g in RHEL 6.3.

Comment: Is it a custom Application? can you see the rest end point? The Problem might be in the custom application, and not in ArcGIS Server

Comment: @Firman: Without more details on the actual problem, or even a screenshot showing what the users see as missing, it would be like hunting in the dark. I think it would benefit everyone if you post some screen shots and/or error logs.

Comment: Dear all, 
I would like to thank you for all of the comments and I apologize that I didn't response promptly.
I couldn't receive any screenshot, but maybe the network performance is one of the reasons.

PING 10.12.4.153 (10.12.4.153) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.12.5.53 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.12.5.53 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 10.12.4.153: icmp_req=25 ttl=62 time=102 ms
From 10.12.5.53 icmp_seq=59 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.12.5.53 icmp_seq=60 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 10.12.4.153: icmp_req=124 ttl=62 time=14.0 ms